# PHP DOM Remove Child From xml

Tags: php, xml

I cant Remove the  Child
i'm trying to delete one data with $user_code = $user_code_ac

delete.php

```
include "../config/config_all.php";
user_code_ac = "Fri05291220192005212c000000";
$user_codez = "Fri05291220192005212c000000";
$um_code = "16Fri091220192038401um000000";
$xmlq = simplexml_load_file('../umum/likes/'.$user_codez.'/likecode/'.$um_code.'.xml')or 
die("Error");
$likecode = $xmlq->xpath('/likes/user_code[contains(text(), '.$user_code_ac.')]');
foreach($likecode as $lc){
    if($lc == $user_code_ac){
        unset($xmlq->user_code[$lc]);
    }
}
file_put_contents('../umum/likes/'.$user_codez.'/likecode/'.$um_code.'.xml' ,$xmlq->saveXML());
```

16Fri091220192038401um000000.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<likes>
  <user_code>Fri05291220192005212c000000</user_code>/* this data I'm trying 
  to delete */
  <user_code>tue02311220192005212c000000</user_code>
</likes>
```

i have try many different ways from google but when i make the php like this

```
foreach($likecode as $lc){
        unset($xmlq->user_code);
}
```

it's delete all the child

Comment: you are trying to delete only one ?

Comment: `$parent->removeChild($child)`

Comment: i just trying delete one with user_code = Fri05291220192005212c000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finnaly i understand hahahahaha

```
include "../config/config_all.php";
$user_codez = "Fri05291220192005212c000000";
$um_code = "16Fri091220192038401um000000";
$xmlq = 
simplexml_load_file('../umum/likes/'.$user_codez.'/likecode/'.$um_code.'.xml')or 
die("Error");
$index = 0;
$i = 0;
foreach($xmlq->user_code as $lc){
    if($lc['id']==$user_code_ac){
        $index = $i;
        break;
    }
    $i++;
}
unset($xmlq->user_code[$index]);
file_put_contents('../umum/likes/'.$user_codez.'/likecode/'.$um_code.'.xml', $xmlq- 
>asXML());
```